# mongo shell working in UBUNTU but 'mongod start' doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ubuntu-server

command mongo gives the interactive shell on command but when this command is executed as `sudo systemctl enable mongod.service`, it gives following output.
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist.`

I am using ubuntu 17 machine.

also `sudo systemctl start mongodb` doesn't give any output.

on running `sudo service mongodb status`
it gives output as

```
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-02-15 23:08:02 IST; 1min 37s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 19137 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=${SOCKETPATH} --config ${CONF} $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 19137 (code=exited, status=100)

Feb 15 23:08:02 gd systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Feb 15 23:08:02 gd systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Feb 15 23:08:02 gd systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 15 23:08:02 gd systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your mongo service is called `mongodb`, pretty sure it should called `mongod` like you tried! Similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921753/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found).

If your service is called `mongodb` you could so try:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

When starting a service it wont give you any `output` and just returns back to the prompt. You can use `systemctl status` like you’ve done or you look st [`journalctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/journalctl.1.html)

If you’re using `systemctl` then you can check the service status by running:

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb.service
```